# Profile app won't verify

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

**Problem**

I am a jailbreaker, having used Unc0ver to jailbreak my phone. But I cant verify the profile. When I do it just untrusts it again. I have trusted it before. Being on Wi-Fi doesn't seem to make a difference, although I did take my phone camping and that's when it first stopped trusting the profile.

**Research**

I have tried to look at other forums on this website, but they didn't help because they were talking about illegal apps (such as AppValley and PandaHelper).

How might I try resolving this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime I've edited your question a little, but can I ask you to also [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367552/edit) it so that there's no ambiguity as to what *profile* you're talking about? At present that could be interpreted a number of ways.

Comment: The profile name is Zhuhai Hengqin Bright Scholar Managment Consulting Co., LTd. As a said. They own unc0ver `A Jailbreak app`

Comment: How can i add screenshots.

Comment: Ah, well, I didn't get that from your post, so that'd be good to clarify. When you edit your post you'll see there's a toolbar at top of the edit window. You can click on the image icon to add an image such as a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have any reason, i cant verfiy my app.@Monomeeth

Comment: You need to be patient as this is a Q&A site and traffic isn't always busy (when you posted your question most of the world was sleeping). :) Also, the jailbreaking community isn't very big, so not everyone is in a position to help you. In the meantime have you contacted the people behind Unc0ver yet? A problem verifying the profile doesn't mean it's at *your* end, it could be at theirs.

Answer (score 1):

The profile for the jailbreak was revoked by Apple, and you need to reinstall the app from wherever you installed it.

I would recommend using [ignition.fun](https://app.ignition.fun/) to install it again. The ignition.fun website will say at the top whether their applications are signed or not, which will tell you if you can install apps such as unc0ver from the website or not.

If you don't want to have to deal with the jailbreak apps being revoked, you can install the tweak ReProvision from the repository https://repo.incendo.ws which will allow you to automatically resign apps using your Apple ID.